# POSTMAN and PHP CURL for Text-raw with -L options command

Tags: php, api, curl, postman, php-curl

I have a simple command to execute on my postman with the "raw-text" to get information from an API so that the continuation I use it with the CURL function on php except that the command displays me error

> “{"message":"'fef229d3bebeedf618cfe2eea6b3233158e65cb349dc200586af334898c792f60c2f12ce07174fed2d07a68b87cd6c7912b5a480a367facc482bd66872c595bfd1a917beedb210315a94fe172a9581354cdea3cf12bcc6c49c80f756f3da4e310a7f242efb9566e5af276d341d4eca48d4d8f93c1f27bc4ee2a056e940125ea7' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer fef229d3bebeedf618cfe2eea6b3233158e65cb349dc200586af334898c792f60c2f12ce07174fed2d07a68b87cd6c7912b5a480a367facc482bd66872c595bfd1a917beedb210315a94fe172a9581354cdea3cf12bcc6c49c80f756f3da4e310a7f242efb9566e5af276d341d4eca48d4d8f93c1f27bc4ee2a056e940125ea7'.”}"

So I don't know exactly where the problem comes from I show you the command:

```
curl 'https://api.example.com/x/t' \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <PARTNER_ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
    -L
```

I can see the -H that suits CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER but the
-L I don't know what function is it? if someone could help me?

**Problem to solve :**

- First : run the command with Postman Text-raw (GET)
- Second : The function for the -L Option Curl PHP*
  Thanks

Comment: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-L

Comment: thanks but the problem is on the command when i used with Postman imported by raw text is not worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed the command with another API Soft "**Insomnia**" and my command work so i dont know why with POSTMAN the request get status "**403 Forbidden**"

Answer (score 0):

**You can import to postman directly using curl:**

Just click import>raw text and paste the curl command . Now click continue and then click import

[image]

**What is -L:**
the curl you gave is not curl PHP its a regular php and -L is for location

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-L

> -L, --location
>
> (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a
> different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX
> response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new
> place. If used together with -i, --include or -I, --head, headers from
> all requested pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl
> only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes
> curl to a different host, it won't be able to intercept the
> user+password. See also --location-trusted on how to change this. You
> can limit the amount of redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs
> option.
>
> When curl follows a redirect and if the request is a POST, it will do
> the following request with a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or
> 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same unmodified method.
>
> You can tell curl to not change POST requests to GET after a 30x
> response by using the dedicated options for that: --post301, --post302
> and --post303.
>
> The method set with -X, --request overrides the method curl would
> otherwise select to use

**IN postman try :**

[image]

Comment: i get this error message " not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer " 

but when i do this command : 

curl -X GET "https://api.example.com/v1/partners/<PARTNER_ID>/devices?limit=10&start=0" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <PARTNER_ACCESS_TOKEN>" ==>  is worked

the command that not work is this one : 

curl 'https://api.sencrop.com/v1/me' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <PARTNER_ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  -L

i think the option -L is the option that no worked my command on text-raw i cant understand where is the problem exactly !

Comment: Why with the first command worked and the second failed !

Comment: PS: when i taped the command with the option -L in the terminal is worked but not in POSTMAN with text-raw !

Comment: Unless you provide the exact command you use it's hard to help further

Comment: The status is : 403 Forbidden

Comment: The command is this one : `curl 'https://api.example.com/v1/me' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <PARTNER_ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  -L` 

on terminal is worked but not in the POSTMAN

Comment: @Garrix in postman whether you were able to import using import>text-raw>paste curl?

Comment: in postman goto headers and delete the automatically added header authotization , then goto authorization tab and choose bearer token and give your token

Comment: yes i try it but no worked and when i am used another API call "Insomnia " it's worked i dont know why with postman dont work !!

Comment: Please add the code you used for insomnia

Comment: the same `curl 'https://api.example.com/v1/me' \   -H "Authorization: Bearer <PARTNER_ACCESS_TOKEN>" \   -L` 

of corse with the real adress and the <Patner_access_token> i cant publish is privacy

Comment: Can you add screenshot of what you trying in Postman

Answer (score 0):

This is the error that it's displayed after the curl Raw-text import from POSTMAN
[image: Error Postman]